# reuse temporary table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
(SELECT id,content,userid FROM article WHERE type='A' LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT c.id,c.content,c.userid FROM comment AS c
JOIN (SELECT id,content,userid FROM article WHERE type='A' LIMIT 10) AS a
ON c.articleid = a.id)
```

How can I reuse instead of requerying this temporary table `SELECT id,content,userid FROM article WHERE type='A' LIMIT 10`?

Comment: Reuse how? What do you want to do?

Comment: @juergend I just think there might be a better solution than requerying this tmp table.

Comment: Maybe. But we still don't know what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @juergend Actually, I'm trying to merge my 2 queries with `union`. Just because, I feel that this tmp table can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a view for the statement you want to reuse and give it an appropriate name.

Answer (score 0):

This sortof achieves what you asked.

```
SELECT 
   c.id,c.content,c.userid,
   a.id,a.content,a.userid
FROM comment AS c
   JOIN article AS a ON c.articleid = a.id
WHERE a.type='A'

# This will limit #comments + #articles, not usable
# Removing it means a lot of useless data being transferred
LIMIT 10
```

You're gonna have to use multiple queries. Or accept transfer of data that won't be used.

Furthermore you'll have to filter out the double articles you'll get back